# Access specific data in childByAutoId Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to find every auto id with a specific Username and change values in that specific AutoID.

Every auto id that has the username that i am looking for. Then change a specific value on all auto IDs that matches my specified username by string.

So every AutoID that has Username: "s7iytsdifytgsfyg" (example)

Then change all those Auto ids photo_url value.

[image]

[image]

```
//configureAuth()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateValue(_ :)), name: Notification.Name("TIME_TO_UPDATE"), object: nil)


func updateValue(_ notification: Notification) {

        //Firebase Initialization
        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
        //var storage: FIRStorageReference!
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        //storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()


        //Get Data from database resend to database
        ref.child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""

        for key in self.keys {
            self.ref.child("general_room").child(key).updateChildValues(["photo_rul": firebaseUserPhotoURL])
        }

        })
    }

    func changeChatPhoto() {

        //Firebase Initialization
        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        let observer = ref.child("general_room").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let messages = snapshot.value as? [String: Dictionary<String, String>]
            for (key, value) in messages! {
                if value["user_name"] == userID { // Field you want to find
                    self.keys.append(key) // keep track of the key (auto id)
                }
            }
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("TIME_TO_UPDATE"), object: nil)
        })

        // Just observe for one time
        ref.child("general_room").removeObserver(withHandle: observer)


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, you just need to find all keys containing the `username` then update its value.

```
ref.child("general_room").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let general_room = snapshot.value as! [String: Dictionary<String, String>]
        for (key, value) in general_room {
            if value["user_name"] == "HELLO WORLD" { // Field you want to find
                self.keys.append(key) // keep track of the key (auto id)
            }
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("TIME_TO_UPDATE"), object: nil)
    })
```

Also I register the `Notification` in viewDidLoad which tells me all data is retrieved from firebase.

```
var keys = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateValue(_ :)), name: Notification.Name("TIME_TO_UPDATE"), object: nil)
}

func updateValue(_ notification: Notification) {
    for key in keys {
       self.ref.child("general_room").child(key).updateChildValues(["photo_rul": "http://google.com"])
    }
}
```

Comment: on update values? you have child("messages") do you mean general_room?

Comment: yep, my apologies.

Comment: while calling it in viewDidLoad

Comment: I don't get it. Your question is looking for all auto ids and change its value with matching username. What do you mean pass a value to update function in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I just edited my code above it doesnt sem to be working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138505/discussion-between-wei-jay-and-codechicksrock).

Comment: This is your second time helping me out and I want to thank you so much. sorry for the confusion but I was able to work it out. Thanks so much.